# Badly contained in a string except when I store it in C++ class

Tags: c++, string, opengl, shader

I'm training in openGL programmation and I want to create my own classes to make me life easier. However, I'm faced to a problem in my Shader class.

My Shader class is composed of one C++ string (the name of the shader) and two others C strings (which contain the code of the fragment and vertex shaders).

Then, during initialization, I read my files to stock every character into my both C string. At this moment, these two variable are correctly filled, but if I try to read them by my `getVertex()` method, it does not show me at all what must be in it.

Fragment and Vertex shaders code must be stock in a `const GLchar *` because of `glShaderSource()` which is used to load shaders. Here is the prototype of this function: `void glShaderSource(GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar **string, const GLint *length);`.

I have already tried to use basic `const char *` as `const GLchar *`, but it is even.

I also tried to stock shaders code into C++ strings and convert them into C string in the main but it it does not change anything.

Here is my code with the debug print:

-main.cpp

```
#include "head.h"

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

int main(){

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);    //For MacOS


    /*Window initialization*/
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello Window!", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL){
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);


    /*GLAD initialization*/
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)){
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    /*Initialize shaders*/
    Shader myShaders("Hello");

    std::cout << "Main Print\n" << myShaders.getVertex() << std::endl;

    /*Triangle Vertices*/
    /*float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };*/


    /*Rectangle Vertices*/
    float vertices[] = {
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // top left 
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,   // first triangle
        1, 2, 3    // second triangle
    };

    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    /*Define the type of the VBO*/
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    /*Copy vertices into the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER object (VBO)*/
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    /*Creating a VS object*/
    unsigned int vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    /*Link the VS code to the VS object*/
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &myShaders.getVertex(), NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    /*Testing the VS compilation*/
    int  success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    /*As the VS, same for FS*/
    unsigned int fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &myShaders.getFragment(), NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }


    /*Creating the program Shader*/
    unsigned int shaderProgram;
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    /*Testing PS compilation*/
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }


    /*Deleting shaders already used*/
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    /*Activating our shader*/
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


    /*How to interprets data*/
    /*(layout (location = 0),vec3,type of the vec,for [-1.0;1.0],stride worked with 0 too, offset to begin*/
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    /*Creating Vertex Array Object*/
    unsigned int VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    // 1. Lier le Vertex Array Object (VAO)
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    // 2. Copier les sommets dans un tampon pour qu’OpenGL les utilise
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // 3. Initialiser les pointeurs d’attributs de sommets
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    /*Creating an EBO for tell the order of vertices to being draw*/
    unsigned int EBO;    
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    /*GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER for EBO*/
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    /*Setting the view*/
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);


    /*To get a thread style*/
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);


    /*Render Loop*/
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glClearColor(0.5f, 0.3f, 0.6f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        processInput(window);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        //glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        /*(Kind of primitive to use, begin of vertices tab, end of vertices tab)*/
        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


        /*6 for length of EBO*/
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }


    glfwTerminate();


    return 0;
}


/*Resize*/
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height){
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}


/*Handle inputs*/
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window){
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}
```

-shader.hpp:

```
#pragma once

class Shader {

public:
    Shader(std::string const& name) : name_(name){
        std::string tmp;
        std::ifstream stream("./shaders/" + name_ + ".fs");
        if(stream) {
            while (stream.good()) {
                tmp += stream.get();
            }
        }
        fragment_ = tmp.c_str();

        stream.close();

        tmp = "";

        stream.open("./shaders/" + name_ + ".vs");
        if(stream) {
            while (stream.good()) {
                tmp += stream.get();
            }
        }
        vertex_ = tmp.c_str();

        stream.close();
        std::cout << "Shader Initialization Print\n" << vertex_ << "\n\n";
    }

    void initialize(){
        if (name_.size() > 0) {
            std::string tmp;
            std::ifstream stream("./shaders/" + name_ + ".fs");
            if (stream) {
                while (stream.good()) {
                    tmp += stream.get();
                }
            }
            fragment_ = tmp.c_str();
            stream.close();

            tmp = "";

            stream.open("./shaders/" + name_ + ".vs");
            if (stream) {
                while (stream.good()) {
                    tmp += stream.get();
                }
            }
            vertex_ = tmp.c_str();
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    void setName(std::string const& name) {
        name_ = name;
    }

    std::string getName() {
        return name_;
    }

    void setFragment(std::string const& fragment) {
        fragment_ = fragment.c_str();
    }

    const GLchar* & getFragment() {
        return fragment_;
    }

    void setVertex(std::string const& vertex) {
        vertex_ = vertex.c_str();
    }

    const GLchar* & getVertex() {
        std::cout << "getVertex() Print\n" << vertex_ << "\n\n";
        return vertex_;
    }

private:
    std::string name_;
    const GLchar * vertex_;
    const GLchar * fragment_;
};
```

-head.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "shader.hpp"
```

-Trace of execution

```
Shader Initialization Print
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
} 

getVertex() Print
¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦  

Main Print
¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦  
getVertex() Print
¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦  

ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"

ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"

ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::COMPILATION_FAILED
Vertex info
-----------
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"
(0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link

Fragment info
-------------
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"
(0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link
```

Actually, I expect to get what shader initialization print everywhere I call my `getVertex()`/`getFragment()` methods.

Comment: The `setFrahment` function attempts to store the`c_str ()` of a temporary string.  You make the same mistake in various parts of your code.  What will happen when the temporary dies off?  The string data also dies.

Comment: The obvious solution is to make `vertex_` and `fragment_` C++ strings like `name_`. Any reason that's not possible?

Comment: Reply to @PaulMcKenzie: So, should I directly store the data in `` `vertex _``` & ```fragment _``` variables rather than using a temp variable?

Comment: @3t13nn3 No that won't help. The problem is that the return C string from `c_str` has a limitted extent. It's inheritently dangerous to store it anywhere, because, depending on what happens elsewhere in your code, it may become invalid.

Comment: Reply to @John: I must use ```const GLchar *``` for directly call my getter in the ```glShaderSource()``` function. But I'll try to cast it into my main, but that will not be clean for my use.

Comment: @3t13nn3 What you need to do then is **copy** the characters to your own privately allocated area which you have full control over. You cannot rely on the lifetime of the pointer returned from `c_str()`.

Comment: @john not mandatory, OP just may maintain `std::string` lifetime properly

Comment: To @john, I've tried to use C++ string then to stock my datas, obviously, print are working, but by casting my string as this ```glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1,(const GLchar **) &myShaders.getVertex(), NULL);```, it doesn't work, i got an error during loading my shader. Execution: ```ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting "::" at token "<undefined>"```

Comment: @3t13nn3 You're not addressing the real problem, casting is rarely a good idea. openGL needs a pointer to a pointer, you have to provide that, and do so in a way where the pointer is still valid when openGl tries to use it. I'll write an answer with a couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is an issue when you read the file you've to evaluate [`stream.good()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) after the character is read but befor the cahrater is add to the string. Note, [`.get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) sets the `eofbit` when it fails to read a character, but not when th kast charater was read:

```cpp
std::string tmp;
std::ifstream stream("./shaders/" + name_ + ".fs");

while (true) {
    char c = stream.get();
    if (!stream)
        break;
    tmp += c;
}
```

Anyway i recmmend to use [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istreambuf_iterator/):

```cpp
std::ifstream stream("./shaders/" + name_ + ".fs");
std::string tmp = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

`getVertex` and `getFragment`. Should return a reference to a pointer to the shader code characters (`const GLchar*&`). So you've to store the shader code in an attribute. I recommend to stroe the code in a [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/). Further you need an attribute of type `const GLchar*`, which holds a pointer to the code and can be returned by reference:

```cpp
class Shader {
public:

   // ...

   void setVertex(std::string const& vertex) {
        vertex_ = vertex;
        vs_ptr_ = vertex_.c_str();
    }

    const GLchar*& getVertex() {
        return vs_ptr_;
    }

private:

    // ...

    std::string vertex_;
    const GLchar *vs_ptr_;
};
```

The entire class my look as follows:

```cpp
class Shader {

public:
    Shader(std::string const& name) 
        : name_(name){
        initialize();
    }

    void initialize(){
        if (name_.empty())
            return;

        std::ifstream stream("./shaders/" + name_ + ".fs");
        std::string tmp = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()); 
        stream.close();
        setFragment(tmp);

        stream.open("./shaders/" + name_ + ".vs");
        tmp = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        stream.close();
        setVertex(tmp);
    }

    void setName(std::string const& name) {
        name_ = name;
    }

    std::string getName() {
        return name_;
    }

    void setFragment(std::string const& fragment) {
        fragment_ = fragment;
        fs_ptr_ = fragment_.c_str();
    }

    const GLchar*& getFragment() {
        return fs_ptr_;
    }

    void setVertex(std::string const& vertex) {
        vertex_ = vertex;
        vs_ptr_ = vertex_.c_str();
    }

    const GLchar*& getVertex() {
        return vs_ptr_;
    }

private:
    std::string name_;
    std::string vertex_;
    std::string fragment_;
    const GLchar *vs_ptr_;
    const GLchar *fs_ptr_;
};
```

Comment: Ok, it's work. If I got it, the problem was about the lifetime of my string which is used to get the C string pointer ?

Comment: @3t13nn3 Yes it is. The pointer points to a "volatile" memory. It points to the buffer of an object which is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to handle this. It uses a `string` and also stores the result of `c_str()` on that string. The point is that by storing the pointer as well as the string it is based on you make sure that the pointer remains valid for as long as the string is valid.

```
class Shader
{
public:
    void setVertex(std::string const& vertex) {
        vertex_ = vertex;
        vertexPtr_ = vertex_.c_str(); // this must be vertex_ not vertex, otherwise we have exactly the same problem as before
    }

    const GLchar* & getVertex() {
        std::cout << "getVertex() Print\n" << vertex_ << "\n\n";
        return vertexPtr_;
    }

private:
    string vertex_;
    const GLchar* vertexPtr_;
};
```

This is untested code.

C++ is not a language where data remains valid as long as it is accessible (unlike Java for instance). You cannot program C++ without understanding the *lifetime* of the objects you create. Your program got the types correct but failed to understand that the pointer was invalid by the time you used it. This version keeps the string and the pointer to it *together* so that both have the same lifetime.